# How to group Left Outer Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, group-by, left-join

I have two models, `User` and `Telephone`. User has many telephones.

I'm making a list on active admin and if user has two phones I would like to group them together. I need a raw sql query, and the one that I wrote gives two separate rows.

What I want:

`John    Legend   123456, 654321`

What I get:

`John    Legend   123456`
`John    Legend   654321`

This is my query:

```
      a = "SELECT user.id, user.first_name, user.last_name, telephone.id AS telephone_id, telephone.number AS telephone_number,
      FROM users 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN telephones ON telephones.user_id = user.id
      GROUP BY users.id, telephones.user_id, telephones.number, telephones.id
      ORDER BY user.id DESC"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Postgres 9.0+, then you may use the `STRING_AGG` function here:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.first_name,
    u.last_name,
    STRING_AGG(t.number, ',') AS telephone_number
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN telephones t
    ON t.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY
    u.id
ORDER BY
    u.id DESC;
```

I only included the three columns which your expected actually shows, though you may add other columns if you want.